# Change mysql timezone from phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timezone

I am trying to change the timezone of my database. I am on **shared server** and database support guys can not change it for me only. Time zone is currently `+1:00`  I want it as `+05:30`. I searched and tried following but nothing worked.

```
date_default_timezone_set('timezone_name');
```

Added to my `index.php` file.

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'timezone_name';
```

It says access restricted.

```
SET time_zone = timezone_name
```

Query run now row affected.

My site is hosted on site-ground us server.

Comment: Are you on a shared server?Contact the admin.

Comment: Sorry to say but I don't know.

Comment: Why do you want to set the timezone global? I would recommend to define the desired timezone for each connection, that way you are save to server side changes.

Comment: OK in case you are,hosting is unlikely to want to change the timezone.Another hack is to add the needed interval to your time `+ INTERVAL 4 HOUR` or whatever to your queries.Yeah,it\`s annoying.OR maybe try `SET SESSION time_zone = 'yourtime';`

Comment: Yes currently I am doing by modifying quires, but I need to update it on sql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I am on **shared server** my provider did not change it only for me. So after search I fount that, I have to use `datetime` type on sql instead of current time stamp and as  madipradhana said I was updated my `php.ini` or `.htaccess` .

Answer (score 3):

Probably you can change the timezone in .htacess without touching your PHP scripts or MySQL query. Open up your `.htaccess` file, enter the command as below.

```
SetEnv TZ your_timezone
```

For example, enter this command if your location in Jakarta

```
SetEnv ID Asia/Jakarta
```

Refer to the link below for available timezone:

http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: Surely that should be 'SetEnv TZ Asia/Jakarta' not 'SetEnv ID Asia/Jakarta' - and this will only work if 'Asia/Jakarta' is known to the timezone database and the webservr is Apache, AND php is running as mod_php. Not to mention the fact that *which* TZ database the PHP install uses depends on the PHP build.

Comment: Either `SetEnv ID Asia/Jakarta` or `SetEnv TZ Asia/Jakarta` works fine on me. Sorry, I didn't mention that the command above is an example if you want to set timezone to Asia/Jakarta. I've edited my post.

Answer (score 2):

As you are on shared server use `date()` of php and set `date_default_timezone_set('timezone_name');` to your `index.php`